Не удается сгенерировать ссылку на подтверждение почты
Сделал форму и юзера через make user и make registration-form
Мой контроллер
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Security\EmailVerifier;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\Exception\VerifyEmailExceptionInterface;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(private EmailVerifier $emailVerifier)
    {
    }

    #[Route('/register', name: 'app_register')]
    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // encode the plain password
            $user->setPassword(
                $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            // generate a signed url and email it to the user
            $this->emailVerifier->sendEmailConfirmation('app_verify_email', $user,
                (new TemplatedEmail())
                    ->from(new Address('web@****.ru', 'Test Test'))
                    ->to($user->getEmail())
                    ->subject('Подтверждение по Email')
                    ->htmlTemplate('registration/confirmation_email.html.twig')
            );

            // do anything else you need here, like send an email

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }

        return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/verify/email', name: 'app_verify_email')]
    public function verifyUserEmail(Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {
        $id = $request->query->get('id');

        if (null === $id) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }

        $user = $userRepository->find($id);

        if (null === $user) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }

        // validate email confirmation link, sets User::isVerified=true and persists
        try {
            $this->emailVerifier->handleEmailConfirmation($request, $user);
        } catch (VerifyEmailExceptionInterface $exception) {
            $this->addFlash('verify_email_error', $translator->trans($exception->getReason(), [], 'VerifyEmailBundle'));

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }

        // @TODO Change the redirect on success and handle or remove the flash message in your templates
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Your email address has been verified.');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
    }
}

Мой EmailVerifier
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\Exception\VerifyEmailExceptionInterface;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\VerifyEmailHelperInterface;

class EmailVerifier
{
    public function __construct(
        private VerifyEmailHelperInterface $verifyEmailHelper,
        private MailerInterface $mailer,
        private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
    ) {
    }

    public function sendEmailConfirmation(string $verifyEmailRouteName, User $user, TemplatedEmail $email): void
    {
        $signatureComponents = $this->verifyEmailHelper->generateSignature(
            $verifyEmailRouteName,
            (string) $user->getId(),
            $user->getEmail(),
            ['id' => $user->getId()]
        );

        $context = $email->getContext();
        $context['signedUrl'] = $signatureComponents->getSignedUrl();
        $context['expiresAtMessageKey'] = $signatureComponents->getExpirationMessageKey();
        $context['expiresAtMessageData'] = $signatureComponents->getExpirationMessageData();

        $email->context($context);

        $this->mailer->send($email);
    }

    /**
     * @throws VerifyEmailExceptionInterface
     */
    public function handleEmailConfirmation(Request $request, User $user): void
    {
        $this->verifyEmailHelper->validateEmailConfirmationFromRequest($request, (string) $user->getId(), $user->getEmail());

        $user->setVerified(true);

        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}

Сообщение на почту уходит, но при переходе по ссылке

The link to verify your email is invalid. Please request a new link.

Версия symfony 7
Разработка локально в докере
Попробовал вывести параметры

[2024-07-31T06:48:40.768182+00:00] app.ERROR: Email verification
failed: The link to verify your email is invalid. Please request a new
link.
{"request_params":{"expires":"1722412100","id":"5","signature":"kyzxor2V5WImlWuE3lRyE2qiCDFFVI4hU4iQixjfK5o=","token":"p1xjadDSxJyAff0OnkAg3lOSmWj7pmppNy4jgG5TcBc=","uri":"/verify/email"},"expected_signature":"http://localhost/verify/email?expires=1722412120&id=5&signature=csTPzpES61dQ2ZTyLJcVH1U%2Ft5VMLx%2F4i9b2x%2Fyf%2Bk8%3D&token=p1xjadDSxJyAff0OnkAg3lOSmWj7pmppNy4jgG5TcBc%3D"}
[]

Отличается expires и signature. В чем может быть проблема? Как такое вообще дебажить?
